# По номеру выводит название из другой базы

Tags: sql

Мне нужно по номеру вывести название из другой базы.
Есть 1 база с номером модели, есть 2 база с номером модели и ещё одной колонкой названия. Нужно, чтобы в 1 базе, возле номера модели шло название по этому номеру из другой модели.

Запрос 2 базы:

```
SELECT [M],[NP] FROM [NSI].[dbo].[SprMod]
```

Запрос 1 базы:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nomer FROM Kolodka WHERE Data_udolenya IS NULL ORDER BY Nomer ASC
```

[image: 1 база]
1 база

[image: 2 база]
2 база

Comment: Другой базы или таблицы?!

Comment: базы, они из разных баз

Comment: и в чем в данном случае будет отличие в этой базе таблица или в другой? join будет точно таким же.